# Best way of coding in hybrid mobile app

Tags: mobile

What is the best way of coding in hybrid mobile app. I am researching on hybrid app . I need to know what is the proper and best way in coding the hybrid mobile app. Way in the sense like oops and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PhoneGap, Sencha Touch, JQuery Mobile.

Sencha Touch would use ExtJs which is Object Oriented JavaScript Framework.

In order to develop hybrid application mostly you should be aware of HTML5, Javascript.

Comment: i know about that. I am not asking about technology. There will be a standard way of coding .Like OOPS concept in javascript . I am talking about way of coding. I need to know standard , best and proper way of coding in any hybrid app tech like phonegap , sencha touch and jquery mobile

Comment: Each Technology mentioned has provided extensive documenetation about how to write a applciation, i suggest you read some documentation

Comment: Not that , i was asking about proper way like in javascript we can go oops concept or we can go without oops .So i am asking in that way.

Comment: Offcourse without a shadow of a doubt OOP is the way top go

Comment: There is a question in the exam which i am going to write in hybrid app development. That question is "WHat is the best way of coding in the Hybrid mobile app development" . What should i answer.